# Receiving Sentry error logs from Azure Devops (After Release)

Tags: .net, azure-devops, sentry

I have a .Net Project that has integrated Sentry.io logging. Basic Exception handling over an API call(if api call and deserialization fails). The repo, build and release pipelines lives in Azure Devops

I saw thousands of errors coming through and thought it was my app running in IIS that caused this but I noticed that the source of the error was a path that looks like devops (D:\a\1\s...).

The errors only stops if I remove the exception handling and build/release it. To test my theory (after it stopped) I added the error handling back in and rereleased the latest build and it started again. (My release pipeline only extracts files, stops IIS, transfer files, start IIS)

Any idea what could be causing this/avoid it happening in the future?

Edit: I added a step in to delete the extracted files but this doesn't solve the issue

Even though I have a private release agent on my server. The error path is on par with files hosted in Azure Devops and not on my server

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps tests from your project that run in Azure DevOps are calling code that initializes Sentry.

While one *could* use Sentry in that way, I don't recommend it.  The Sentry .NET SDK is primarily designed to be using from an actual application, and initialized only once for the lifetime of that application.

Unit tests often run in parallel within the same process, which could be initializing the SDK repeatedly.

I suggest avoiding initializing Sentry in your unit tests.  There are several ways to do that:

- You can refactor your code to prevent calls to `SentrySDK.Init` or `UseSentry`, etc. from tests at all.
- You might be able to move your Sentry DSN to an environment-specific configuration file, and only load it at production time.
- You could try to detect the Azure Pipelines environment and not initialize Sentry in such case.  For example:

  ```
  // The "AGENT_ID" env var will be populated in an ADO Pipeline
  if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AGENT_ID") == null)
  {
      SentrySDK.Init();
  }
  ```

Comment: For others that may read this, there are a variety of ways to detect different CI environments.  Many of them can be found [in this code](https://github.com/VerifyTests/DiffEngine/blob/main/src/DiffEngine/BuildServerDetector.cs).

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I figured out the issue. It was a bit of a headache as the path threw me off thinking the issue was happening somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I found out that your server hosts the files (Build/Release) when you install an azure devops release agent on a private server.

The issue was never within the agent itself but there was an issue in the code. the only problem was that when the error occurs....It happens with the path that looks like its on the agent(or the folders where its hosted. D:\a\1\s...) but in fact happening where the app is currently running (C:/Published...).

essentially the path of the file throwing the error is misleading.